# Top level imports supersede lower level imports?

Tags: python, pandas, import, modin

In a jupyter notebook, I have

```
import modin.pandas as pd
import utils
```

`utils.py` has `import pandas as pd`

Does the `pd` in `utils.py` import `pandas`, or `modin.pandas`? If the former, is there a way for me to make `utils.py` use `modin.pandas` from the jupyter notebook, without changing it in the code of `utils.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `utils` module will always import `pandas as pd`, using the `utils` module in another module will not change this even if you import `modins.pandas as pd` in another module. This is because the symbol `pd` is tied to the module dictionary and this module dictionary is isolated from another module's dictionary, which essentially represents the core idea of having different namespaces for different modules.

The way to use `modins.pandas` in `utils` is by updating the symbol `pd`. You can easily do this by replacing the old symbol with new symbol using the `setattr` method:

```
import modin.pandas as pd
import utils

setattr(utils, 'pd', pd)
```